# Visual studio item template $safeitemname$ not working as expected

Tags: c#, visual-studio, parameters, visual-studio-templates

I'm creating a Visual Studio Item template to create a few files which depend on a 'container' file.

The last file `<ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$\I$fileinputname$ View.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Container View.cs</ProjectItem>` creates a view interface that expects a certain model type. **However the `$safeitemname$`** parameter didn't work as I expected.

Output **Container View.cs** file:

```
public interface IIMy_Triplet_View : IView<IMy_Triplet_View_Model>
{
}
```

**Expected:**

```
public interface IMy_Triplet_View : IView<My_Triplet_Model>
{
}
```

**This is the source for the Container View.cs template:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using WebFormsMvp;

namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    public interface $safeitemname$_View : IView<$safeitemname$_Model>
    {
    }
}
```

**And the .vstemplate file**

```
    <VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
      <TemplateData>
        <DefaultName>Model-View-Presenter</DefaultName>
        <Name>Model-View-Presenter</Name>
        <Description>Creates a model-view-presenter triplet</Description>
        <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
        <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
        <Icon>__TemplateIcon.png</Icon>
        <PreviewImage>__PreviewImage.png</PreviewImage>
      </TemplateData>
      <TemplateContent>
        <References>
          <Reference>
            <Assembly>WebFormsMvp</Assembly>
          </Reference>
        </References>
        <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$" ReplaceParameters="false">Container</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$\$fileinputname$ Model.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Container Model.cs</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$\$fileinputname$ Presenter.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Container Presenter.cs</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$\I$fileinputname$ View.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Container View.cs</ProjectItem>
      </TemplateContent>
    </VSTemplate>
```

Answer (score 22):

Solution found here : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/8516524a-22d3-4ed2-b2da-aaafe855fb92/

Add a CustomParameter (last item under TemplateContent) :

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" ... Type="Item">
 <TemplateData>
  ...
 </TemplateData>
 <TemplateContent>
  ...
  <CustomParameters>
   <CustomParameter Name="$basename$" Value="$fileinputname$"/>
  </CustomParameters>
 </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

And use $basename$ in the files instead of $fileinputname$.